# Freq Response Error "Float Object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, signal-processing, autocorrelation, python-sounddevice

So I'm currently working on a code for linear prediction, where we apply the various concepts of linear prediction into a raw audio signal
In this code I have m as the len of the audio that i inputted, now I get this error here when I try to code the frequency response of it:

```
omega = np.pi*m

x_real = np.zeros(m)
x_imaj = np.zeros(m)

for i in range(0, int(m/2)):
    for j in range(1, t_lag): 
        x_real[i] += inv_a[j]*np.cos(j*omega[i])
        x_imaj[i] += inv_a[j]*np.sin(j*omega[i])
            
    x_real[i] = 1-x_real[i]
    
H_2 = 1/np.sqrt(x_real**2+x_imaj**2)

#Frequency Response for Linear Prediction
h_real = np.zeros(m)
h_imaj = np.zeros(m)

for i in range(0, int(m/2)):
    for j in range(1, t_lag): 
        h_real[i] += a[j]*np.cos(j*omega[i])
        h_imaj[i] += a[j]*np.sin(j*omega[i])
    h_real[i] = 1-h_real[i]

H_1 = 1/np.sqrt(h_real**2+h_imaj**2)

#Plotting Frequency Response 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,20))
ax.plot(H_1, color='red', label='A Omega')
ax.plot(H_2, color='blue', label='H Omega')
ax.set_title("Response Frequency",font="times new roman", size=55)
ax5.set_xlabel('Ohm', fontsize='x-small')
ax5.set_ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize='x-small')
fig.tight_layout()
ax.legend(fontsize=50)
plt.show()
```

and the error that i receive is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Armand S\Desktop\Python Biomodelling File\[FP BIOMOD]Linear Prediction_Armand Faris A Surbakti_5023201051.ipynb Cell 12 in <cell line: 8>()
      8 for i in range(0, int(m/2)):
      9     for j in range(1, t_lag): 
---> 10         x_real[i] += inv_a[j]*np.cos(j*omega[i])
     11         x_imaj[i] += inv_a[j]*np.sin(j*omega[i])
     13     x_real[i] = 1-x_real[i]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Which is  a typeerror

Any help of this would be appreciated!

Comment: What are `inv_a` and `m`? One (or both) of them are floats and not arrays (as you might think)

Comment: set a breakpoint in that line and you will see either inv_a or omega are a single float value instead of something subscriptable like a list or array...  float[idx] does not work. Could be because m is a float